# Does lexical scope can only be created between curly braces?

Tags: javascript

Is there a case when curly braces are not required in order to make a new scope where you can declare a local variable? No matter what I think of, it does have curly braces: e.g. blocks, conditions, loops, try/catch etc. And, for example arrow functions without block bodies seem to not create new scopes.

Comment: Arrow functions always create a new scope for their parameters, with or without a block body.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean by "for their parameters"? So parameters can be viewed as variable declarations, right?

Comment: Yes. Declaring a parameter (or in case of destructuring, I wouldn't even call the target identifier a "parameter") does create a local variable in the function scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop with `let` creates a scope:

```
let x = "hello world";
for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) console.log(x); // numbers ...
console.log(x); // "hello world"
```

No `{ }` in that code.

Arrow functions *do* create a new scope, but they do not create a new `this` binding.

```
let x = "hello world";
let y = () => { let x = "new scope"; console.log(x); };
y(); // "new scope"
console.log(x): // "hello world"
```

Comment: Hmm, indeed! Forgot about that. Thanks! :-) So there goes for..of, for..in as well... Something else maybe?

Comment: Right, any of the `for` forms that allow a declaration with `let` or `const` will do it.

Comment: I meant `arrow functions without block bodies`, fixed it. Sorry

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev yes that's true, though there cannot be a `let` or `const` declaration without a block body anyway.